# VS Code: Create a hotkey to focus on the find box?

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS Code, when I use find-and-replace it brings up a little window where I can enter my find and replace terms. I would like to make a keybinding that I can use to focus on the "find" box. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `Ctrl+F` will bring up the Find widget or focus it if focus is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Do you know whether there is a command for that that I could use in macros?

Comment: see `actions.find`

Comment: I will upvote this when I have enough rep. Thanks :)